# declaring pointer to 1-D Array inside 2-D Array in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

This Code works fine in C but not in C++.Can anybody tell how to pass pointer to 1-D Array inside a 2-D array?

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
              int s[5][2]={ 
                          {0,1},   
                          {2,3},
                          {4,5},
                          {6,7},
                          {8,9}   
                };
        }

    int (*p)[2];
    int i,j,*pointer;

       for(i=0;i<=4;i++){
             p=&s[i];
```

This line generates error if I remove (int*) while working fine in C.Its saying cant not convert int(*)[2] to (int*).

```
             pointer=(int*)p;
             printf("\n");

       for(j=0;j<=1;j++)
       {
             printf("%d\t",*(pointer+j));
       }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please Indent your code correctly, make sure braces are placed correctly.

Comment: I am sorry I was getting error again and again that "Please add some context".I tried to indent but I am new to this so I didn't get how to add context.

Comment: @Justin James Could you point out what statement generates the error and what is the message of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if to add missed closing brace then the code is compiled successfuly (at www.ideone.com)

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() 
{
    int s[5][2] = 
    { 
        { 0, 1 },
        { 2, 3 },
        { 4, 5 },
        { 6, 7 },
        { 8, 9 }
    };

    int ( *p )[2];  
    int i, j, *pointer;

    for( i = 0; i <= 4; i++ )
    {
        p = &s[i];
        pointer = (int*)p;
        printf( "\n" );

        for ( j = 0; j <= 1; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d\t", *( pointer + j ) );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
0   1   
2   3   
4   5   
6   7   
8   9
```

Take into account that it would be better to write

```
pointer = *p;
```

instead of

```
pointer = (int*)p;
```

Comment: I exactly wanted to ask this. 

        pointer=*p 
is not working

Comment: C:\TC\INCLUDE\xc.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\TC\INCLUDE\xc.cpp|16|error: cannot convert 'int (*)[2]' to 'int*' in assignment|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Comment: @Justin James  i showed you that the code is compiled. Only make the change i adviced.

Comment: @JustinJames if Vlad's code (with `pointer = *p;` ) does not compile then your compiler is broken, and you should switch to using a good compiler. The error message suggests you might have written `pointer = p;`